# How to get the Auth_State in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to login the site. There are couple of GET request before moving to login screen and on the login screen:

My Request Parameter is:

username=8888888888&password=8888888888&AUTH_STATE=2c83bef4-9ab3-4549-8d3b-243e5864cc78

I know my username and password but when i capture the parameters using firebug, i found that along with that AUTH_STATE also going..

I tried to find the AUTH_STATE parameter in any of the GET Response made before login call.. But i did not find it out.. Is there any way to get that ???

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should be there in the login page. Check the HTML response of the login page.

Comment: are you using SAML authentication??

Comment: I guess the flow should be: Launch your portal --> it will be redirected to login page. This login page should be having the auth_state or you can also check the page header data. If you still cannot find it, check with your Development team

Comment: Got it.. I found it actually, i could not able to see.. when i click login, it is Iframe, so i have to take the source code once iFrame is loaded.. This tip helped me.. :)